# How can I change my code so that the "time limit exceeded" error message does not show up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing Codeforces problem 732A.
How can I change my solution so that there is no error message that claims "Time limit exceeded"?
By the way, I am a beginner coder who has started only but a few weeks ago, so please try to be simple with your help :)

My code:

## 732A

k,r = list(map(int, input().split()))

t = 0

while (((t * 10) + r) % k) != 0:
t = t + 1

print ((((t * 10) + r) // k))

Comment: Please look up minimal example. You cannot expect people to look up external resources for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem, but you should probably link it at least next time. The way you are solving it is correct but involves too many iterations of your while loop which is causing the time limit error. Instead of doing (t*10)+r until you find a multiple of k, you could do something like

```
k,r = list(map(int, input().split()))
temp = k
num = 1
while temp%10 and (temp-r)%10:
    temp+=k
    num+=1

print(num)
```

The way this works is it finds the first multiple of k (or multiple of k minus r) that is divisible by 10, which should be faster than your solution.